# Python import preserving package name

Tags: python

What I want to do is importing module `foo` as `testPkg.foo`, not only `foo`, so `testPkg.foo.bar()` works.

However, when I do `import testPkg`, it does not import modules in the package, while `from testPkg import *` does. Is is possible to preserve package name `testPkg.`?

For example, the directory looks like:

```
test.py
testPkg/
     __init__.py
     foo.py
```

The content of `test.py` is:

```
import testPkg
testPkg.foo.bar()
```

When I execute `test.py`, it makes `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    testPkg.foo.bar()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

The content of  `__init__.py` is:

```
__all__ = ["foo"]
```

The content of `foo.py` is:

```
def bar():
    print("bar")
print("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer.

The content of `__init__.py` should be like:

```
from . import foo
```

Then `import testPkg` imports `foo` as `testPkg.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Um... Maybe `import testPkg.foo as testPkgFoo` and call it using `testPkgFoo.bar()` or maybe it is the `__init__.py` file. Change the first line to just `foo.py`.

Comment: About 7? And the `foo` works well when using `from testPkg import *`, `foo.bar()`.

Comment: Just add all of the names to the `__init__.py` file. Should work after that.